# Single Task Assignment with OptaPlanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have a customer service application with live messaging feature. When a new conversation is started by a client, I want to assign this single conversation to most available customer service represantative (who has min. nubmer of converastions, min. average conversation length and min. average conversation duration). Also I can get the list of c.s.representatives at a moment and the properties dynamically changes. So every time I get this list, I have different c.s.representatives with different properties. I want to implement this optimization feature with OptaPlanner. How can I write my PlanningEntity, PlanningSolution and ConstraintProvider classes?

```
public class CustomerServiceRepresantative {
    private String id;
    private int numberOfConversations;
    private int avgConversationLength;
    private int avgConversationDuration;
    public CustomerServiceRepresantative () {}
}
```

```
public class ConversationTask {
    private int id;
    public ConversationTask() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `@PlanningPin` to pin all your existing assignments, so only your one new assignment is unpinned.
2. Configure the `SolverConfig.withPhases(new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig())` to only run the CH. Give it unlimited termination time, it will terminate when the CH terminates.